# horizontal bar chart in d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have created a bar graph horizontally but there are many more requirements that need to be full filled where I'm facing the problem
Poblems:
1.Even though I was able to remove the X major axis I couldn't hide the labels associated with it.
2.I have to create a dotted lines for 80% and 100.
3.rounded edges of the bar graph
4.Is legend of bar graph

Current code that I'm using is as per below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
          
<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
          
<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
const margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 90},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
const svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

// Parse the Data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/data_to_viz/master/Example_dataset/7_OneCatOneNum_header.csv").then( function(data) {

  // Add X axis
  console.log(data)
  const x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1000])
    .range([ 0, width]);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0))
    .select(".domain").remove()
    

  // Y axis
  const y = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([ 0, height ])
    .domain(data.map(d => d.Country))
    .padding(.1);
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0))

  //Bars
  svg.selectAll("myRect")
    .data(data)
    .join("rect")
    .attr("x", x(0) )
    .attr("y", d => y(d.Country))
    .attr("width", d => x(d.Value))
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
    .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
    

})

</script>
```

**Current Output**
[image]

**[image: Expected Output]**

**Edit 1:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}




</style>
<body>  
<div class="container">
<div class="chart-container"></div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
<script>
var data = [{"legend_value":"A","value":8,"label":"test1"},
            {"legend_value":"B","value":15,"label":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pellentesque vestibulum orci, nec porta tortor eleifend eu."},
            {"legend_value":"C","value":20,"label":"test3"},
            {"legend_value":"D","value":10,"label":"test4"},
            {"legend_value":"E","value":25,"label":"test5"},
            {"legend_value":"F","value":1000,"label":"test6"},
];
for (var i=0;i <data.length;i++){
data[i]["legend_value"]=String.fromCharCode(65+i)
}
console.log(data)
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 350, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var y = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([height, 0])
          .padding(0.2);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([0, width-50]);
          
// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select(".chart-container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 300 300")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.value = +d.value;
  });

  // Scale the range of the data in the domains
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.value; })])
  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.legend_value; }));
  //y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);


var bar_height=Math.min(Math.ceil((height/data.length)-data.length*1),45);
  // append the rectangles for the bar chart
  var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter()
    
    bars.append("path")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      //.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
      .attr("width", function(d) {return x(d.value); } )
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.legend_value); })
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
      .attr("fill", "#056DFF")
      .attr("d",  function (d) {
                    console.log("y.bandwidth()",y.bandwidth())
                    return rightRoundedRect(0,Math.floor(y(d.legend_value)) , x(d.value), y.bandwidth(), 5);
            });
    
function rightRoundedRect(x, y, width, height, radius) {
  return "M" + x + "," + y
       + "h" + (width - radius)
       + "a" + radius + "," + radius + " 0 0 1 " + radius + "," + radius
       + "v" + (height - 2 * radius)
       + "a" + radius + "," + radius + " 0 0 1 " + -radius + "," + radius
       + "h" + (radius - width)
       + "z";
}

bars.append("text")
            .attr("class", "legend_value")
            //y position of the legend_value is halfway down the bar
            .attr("y",  function (d) { 
             return Math.floor(y(d.legend_value)+y.bandwidth()/data.length) + Math.ceil(bar_height/2);
             })
            //x position is 3 pixels to the right of the bar
            .attr("x", 0)
            .style("font-size", function (d) {
                
                return 10;
            })
            .style("font-family","sans-serif")
            .style('fill', '#DCDCDC')
            
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.value;
            })
            //.style("text-anchor", "middle");





  // add the y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0));

</script>
</body>
```

**Current Output After Edit 1**

[image]

**Edit 2:**
*Problems that still remains*

1. Grid lines
2. legends

Updated Code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}




</style>
<body>  
<div class="container">
<div class="chart-container"></div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
<script>
var data = [{"legend_value":"A","value":2,"label":"test1"},
            {"legend_value":"B","value":10,"label":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pellentesque vestibulum orci, nec porta tortor eleifend eu."},
            {"legend_value":"C","value":11,"label":"test3"},
            {"legend_value":"D","value":12,"label":"test4"},
            {"legend_value":"E","value":13,"label":"test5"},
            {"legend_value":"F","value":14,"label":"test6"},
            {"legend_value":"g","value":15,"label":"test7"},
            {"legend_value":"h","value":16,"label":"test8"},
            {"legend_value":"i","value":17,"label":"test9"},
            {"legend_value":"j","value":18,"label":"test10"},
            {"legend_value":"k","value":19,"label":"test11"},
];
for (var i=0;i <data.length;i++){
data[i]["legend_value"]=String.fromCharCode(65+i)
}
console.log(data)
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var y = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([height, 0])
          .padding(0.2);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0,100])
          .range([0, width/2]);
          
// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select(".chart-container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
   
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.value = +d.value;
  });

  // Scale the range of the data in the domains
  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.legend_value; }));
  //y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);


var bar_height=Math.min(Math.ceil((height/data.length)-data.length*1),45);
  // append the rectangles for the bar chart
  var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter()
    
    bars.append("path")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      //.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
      .attr("width", function(d) {return x(d.value); } )
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.legend_value); })
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
      .attr("fill", 
      function (d) {
          if (d.value>0.8*100){
            return "#056DFF";
          }
        return "#6345B5";
      })
      .attr("d",  function (d) {
                    console.log("y.bandwidth()",y.bandwidth())
                    rightRoundedRect(0,Math.floor(y(d.legend_value)) , x(d.value), y.bandwidth(), 5)
                    return rightRoundedRect(0,Math.floor(y(d.legend_value))+(y.bandwidth()/2)-(15/2) , x(d.value),15, 9);
            });
    
function rightRoundedRect(x, y, width, height, radius) {
  return "M" + x + "," + y
       + "h" + (width - radius)
       + "a" + radius + "," + radius + " 0 0 1 " + radius + "," + radius
       + "v" + (height - 2 * radius)
       + "a" + radius + "," + radius + " 0 0 1 " + -radius + "," + radius
       + "h" + (radius - width)
       + "z";
}

bars.append("text")
            .attr("class", "legend_value")
            //y position of the legend_value is halfway down the bar
            .attr("y",  function (d) { 
             return Math.floor(y(d.legend_value)+y.bandwidth()/data.length) + Math.ceil(bar_height/2);
             })
            //x position is 3 pixels to the right of the bar
            .attr("x", 0)
            .style("font-size", function (d) {
                
                return 10;
            })
            .style("font-family","sans-serif")
            .style('fill', '#DCDCDC')
            
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.value;
            })
            //.style("text-anchor", "middle");





  // add the y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0));
      


</script>
</body>
```

*Edit 2 Output*

[image]

**Edit code suggested by Omar**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}


.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 1;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.chart-container, .legend {
  width: 20%;
}


.legend-item {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;

}
.dot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<body>  
<div class="container">
<div class="chart-container"></div>
<div class="legend">
</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
<script>
var data = [{"legend_value":"A","value":2,"label":"test1"},
            {"legend_value":"B","value":3,"label":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pellentesque vestibulum orci, nec porta tortor eleifend eu."},
            {"legend_value":"C","value":4,"label":"test3"},
            {"legend_value":"D","value":5,"label":"test4"},
            {"legend_value":"E","value":6,"label":"test5"},
            {"legend_value":"F","value":14,"label":"test6"},
            {"legend_value":"g","value":15,"label":"test7"},
            {"legend_value":"h","value":16,"label":"test8"},
            {"legend_value":"i","value":17,"label":"test9"},
            {"legend_value":"j","value":18,"label":"test10"},
            {"legend_value":"k","value":100,"label":"test11"},
];
for (var i=0;i <data.length;i++){
data[i]["legend_value"]=String.fromCharCode(65+i)
}
console.log(data)
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var y = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([height, 0])
          .padding(0.2);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0,100])
          .range([0, width/2]);
          
// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select(".chart-container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
   
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.value = +d.value;
  });

  // Scale the range of the data in the domains
  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.legend_value; }));
  //y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);



var thresholdValues = {
  minValue: 40,
  maxValue: 85
};

      function wrap(text, width,y) {
        console.log("y:-",y);
        var lineNumbers=1;
        text.each(function () {
            var text = d3.select(this),
            line=[],
            lineNumbers=1,
            lineNumber=0,
            words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse();
            words2 = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse();

            style = text.attr("style"),
            mySubString = style.substring(
                    style.lastIndexOf("font-size: ") + 11,
                    style.lastIndexOf("px")
                );
            while (word = words.pop()) {
                line.push(word);
                current_line = line.join(" ");

                if (current_line.length>25 && mySubString!=14){
                    line.pop();
                    current_line = line.join(" ");
                    line = [word];
                    lineNumbers+=1;

                }
                else if (current_line.length>10 && mySubString!=10){
                    line.pop();
                    current_line = line.join(" ");
                    line = [word];
                    lineNumbers+=1;

                }
            }
            append_line=[];
            lineHeight = 1, // ems
            x = text.attr("x");
            //y = -30;

            
            dy = 1, //parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
            tspan = text.text(null)
                        .append("tspan")
                        .attr("x", x)
                        .attr("y", y)
                        .attr("dy", dy + "em");
            while (word = words2.pop()) {
                append_line.push(word);
                tspan.text(append_line.join(" "));
                if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                    append_line.pop();
                    tspan.text(append_line.join(" "));
                    append_line = [word];
                    tspan = text.append("tspan")
                                .attr("x", x)
                                .attr("y", y)
                                .attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em")
                                .text(word);
               }
            }
        });
    }

var bar_height=Math.min(Math.ceil((height/data.length)-data.length*1),45);
  // append the rectangles for the bar chart
  var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter()
    
    bars.append("path")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      //.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
      .attr("width", function(d) {return x(d.value); } )
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.legend_value); })
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
      .attr("fill", 
      function (d) {
          if (d.value>0.8*100){
            return "#056DFF";
          }
        return "#6345B5";
      })
      .attr("d",  function (d) {
                    console.log("y.bandwidth()",y.bandwidth())
                    rightRoundedRect(0,Math.floor(y(d.legend_value)) , x(d.value), y.bandwidth(), 5)
                    return rightRoundedRect(0,Math.floor(y(d.legend_value))+(y.bandwidth()/2)-(15/2) , x(d.value),15, 9);
            });
    
function rightRoundedRect(x, y, width, height, radius) {
  return "M" + x + "," + y
       + "h" + (width - radius)
       + "a" + radius + "," + radius + " 0 0 1 " + radius + "," + radius
       + "v" + (height - 2 * radius)
       + "a" + radius + "," + radius + " 0 0 1 " + -radius + "," + radius
       + "h" + (radius - width)
       + "z";
}

bars.append("text")
            .attr("class", "legend_value")
            //y position of the legend_value is halfway down the bar
            .attr("y",  function (d) { 
             return Math.floor(y(d.legend_value)+y.bandwidth()/data.length) + Math.ceil(bar_height/2);
             })
            //x position is 3 pixels to the right of the bar
            .attr("x",function (d) {
                if (d.value<4){
                    return x(d.value);
                }
             return 0;
            })
            .style("font-size", function (d) {
                
                return 10;
            })
            .style("font-family","sans-serif")
            .style('fill', '#DCDCDC')
            
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.value +"%";
            })
            //.style("text-anchor", "middle");





  // add the y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0));
      
 svg.append("line")
    .attr("class", "avgValue")
    .attr("x1", 0.8 * (width/2))
    .attr("y1", "0")
    .attr("x2", 0.8 * (width/2))
    .attr("y2", height)
    .attr("stroke", "purple")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1")
    .style("stroke-dasharray", ("10,4"))
  
  svg.append("line")
    .attr("class", "maxValue")
    .attr("x1", width/2)
    .attr("y1", "0")
    .attr("x2", width/2)
    .attr("y2", height)
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1")
    .style("stroke-dasharray", ("10,4"))
    
  svg.append("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr('x', width/2)
            .attr('y',+20)
            .style('font-weight', function (d) {
                return 'bold';
            })
            .style('font-size', function (d) {

                return '10';
            })
            .attr('dy', '.35em')
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .text('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
            .text('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .attr('class', 'dotme')
            .text("Maximum Score")
            .call(wrap, 10,-30);
    
      svg.append("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr('x', 0.8*width/2)
            .attr('y',-20)
            .style('font-weight', function (d) {
                return 'bold';
            })
            .style('font-size', function (d) {

                return '10';
            })
            .attr('dy', '.35em')
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .text('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
            .text('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .attr('class', 'dotme')
            .text("Industry Standard")
            .call(wrap, 10, -30);
    
var keys = ["Industry Standard", "Maximum Score"]

var color=["#056EFF","#6345B5"]

// Add one dot in the legend for each name.
svg.selectAll("mydots")
  .data(keys)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", width/2 +50)
    .attr("cy", function(d,i){ return 100 + i*25}) // 100 is where the first dot appears. 25 is the distance between dots
    .attr("r", 7)
    .style("fill", function(d,i){ return color[i]})

// Add one dot in the legend for each name.
svg.selectAll("mylabels")
  .data(keys)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
    .attr("x", width/2 +70)
    .attr("dy", "0em")
    .attr("y", function(d,i){ return 100 + i*25}) // 100 is where the first dot appears. 25 is the distance between dots
    .style("fill", function(d,i){ return "black"})
    .text(function(d){ return d})
    .attr("text-anchor", "left")
    .style("alignment-baseline", "middle");
    //.call(wrap, 10,  (100 + i*25));
</script>

</script>
</body>
```

**Current Output**

[image]
**For Any help I will be really grateful thanks in advance**

Comment: I've answered your question on how to get the vertical dashed lines. For the legend, you can use the same method I'd used on that other question of yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can add the dashed lines:

```
svg.append("line")
        .attr("class", "avgValue")
        .attr("x1", 0.8 * (width/2))
        .attr("y1", "0")
        .attr("x2", 0.8 * (width/2))
        .attr("y2", height)
        .attr("stroke", "purple")
        .attr("stroke-width", "1")
        // The first value in stroke-dasharray refers to the length of a dash, and the second refers to the spacing between dashes
        .style("stroke-dasharray", ("10,4"))
      
      svg.append("line")
        .attr("class", "maxValue")
        .attr("x1", width/2)
        .attr("y1", "0")
        .attr("x2", width/2)
        .attr("y2", height)
        .attr("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("stroke-width", "1")
        .style("stroke-dasharray", ("10,4"))
```

I've modified your function for the rounded corners, because they were slightly off earlier. This is the modified code:

```
function rightRoundedRect(x, y, width, height, radius) {
      return `M ${x},${y}
              h ${width-radius}
              q ${radius},0 ${radius},${radius}
              v ${height - (2*radius)}
              q 0,${radius} -${radius},${radius}
              h -${width - radius}
              z`
    }
```

This is what your code would look like with these additions:

```js
var data = [{"legend_value":"A","value":2,"label":"test1"},
            {"legend_value":"B","value":10,"label":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pellentesque vestibulum orci, nec porta tortor eleifend eu."},
            {"legend_value":"C","value":11,"label":"test3"},
            {"legend_value":"D","value":12,"label":"test4"},
            {"legend_value":"E","value":13,"label":"test5"},
            {"legend_value":"F","value":14,"label":"test6"},
            {"legend_value":"g","value":15,"label":"test7"},
            {"legend_value":"h","value":16,"label":"test8"},
            {"legend_value":"i","value":17,"label":"test9"},
            {"legend_value":"j","value":18,"label":"test10"},
            {"legend_value":"k","value":19,"label":"test11"},
];
for (var i=0;i <data.length;i++){
data[i]["legend_value"]=String.fromCharCode(65+i)
}
console.log(data)
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var y = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([height, 0])
          .padding(0.2);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0,100])
          .range([0, width/2]);
          
// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select(".chart-container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
   
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.value = +d.value;
  });

  // Scale the range of the data in the domains
  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.legend_value; }));
  //y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);


var bar_height=Math.min(Math.ceil((height/data.length)-data.length*1),45);
  // append the rectangles for the bar chart
  var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter()
    
    // This is for the lightgray bars in the background. Same code, just longer width and a fixed color
    bars.append("path")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      //.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
      .attr("width", function(d) {return x(d.value); } )
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.legend_value); })
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
      .attr("fill", 'lightgray')
      .attr("d",  function (d) {
                    console.log("y.bandwidth()",y.bandwidth())
                    rightRoundedRect(0,Math.floor(y(d.legend_value)) , width/2, y.bandwidth(), y.bandwidth()/2)
                    return rightRoundedRect(0,Math.floor(y(d.legend_value))+(y.bandwidth()/2)-(15/2) , width/2,15, 9);
            });
  
  // This is your original code for the bars
  bars.append("path")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      //.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
      .attr("width", function(d) {return x(d.value); } )
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.legend_value); })
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
      .attr("fill", 
      function (d) {
          if (d.value>0.8*100){
            return "#056DFF";
          }
        return "#6345B5";
      })
      .attr("d",  function (d) {
                    console.log("y.bandwidth()",y.bandwidth())
                    rightRoundedRect(0,Math.floor(y(d.legend_value)) , x(d.value), y.bandwidth(), y.bandwidth()/2)
                    return rightRoundedRect(0,Math.floor(y(d.legend_value))+(y.bandwidth()/2)-(15/2) , x(d.value),15, 9);
            });
    
function rightRoundedRect(x, y, width, height, radius) {
  return `M ${x},${y}
          h ${width-radius}
          q ${radius},0 ${radius},${radius}
          v ${height - (2*radius)}
          q 0,${radius} -${radius},${radius}
          h -${width - radius}
          z`
}

bars.append("text")
            .attr("class", "legend_value")
            //y position of the legend_value is halfway down the bar
            .attr("y",  function (d) { 
             return Math.floor(y(d.legend_value)+y.bandwidth()/data.length) + Math.ceil(bar_height/2);
             })
            //x position is 3 pixels to the right of the bar
            .attr("x", 0)
            .style("font-size", function (d) {
                
                return 10;
            })
            .style("font-family","sans-serif")
            .style('fill', '#DCDCDC')
            
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.value;
            })
            //.style("text-anchor", "middle");





  // add the y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0));
      
 // get rid of this code, it's only there so you can see where the line is with regards to the x-axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0))
    .select(".domain").remove()
  
 svg.append("line")
    .attr("class", "avgValue")
    .attr("x1", 0.8 * (width/2))
    .attr("y1", "0")
    .attr("x2", 0.8 * (width/2))
    .attr("y2", height)
    .attr("stroke", "purple")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1")
    .style("stroke-dasharray", ("10,4"))
  
  svg.append("line")
    .attr("class", "maxValue")
    .attr("x1", width/2)
    .attr("y1", "0")
    .attr("x2", width/2)
    .attr("y2", height)
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1")
    .style("stroke-dasharray", ("10,4"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}




</style>
<body>  
<div class="container">
<div class="chart-container"></div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @Omar it worked properly but the issue with legend still exists. can you help me with that I'm trying to get the words one below the other as shown unexpected image output .for now I have upvoted your answer